# mount + verify disk status + disk isnt read/write

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat, hard-drive, mount

Friends and colleagues,

We check the sdb disk to see if this is rw but we get "ew", what is the meaning of that?

```
mount | grep sdb
/dev/sdb on /montoptree/sdb type ext4 (ew,noatime, data=ordered)
```

I am also read the **mount** man page about mount

```
   ro     Mount the filesystem read-only.
   rw     Mount the filesystem read-write.
```

**but not see there the "ew"**

Comment: I've never heard of ew, so searched the source code for mount, ext4, and linux, and didnt spot anything. Where is your storage coming from? Whats the output of `localectl`?

Comment: we fix it by umount -l  /montoptree/sdb ; mount /montoptree/sdb

Comment: now we see rw ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard of it, sounds like a bug, try a lazy unmount and remounting.

```
FS=/montoptree/sdb; umount -l $FS && mount $FS
```